# Parsing Numeric Types with Thousands Separator using TypeConverter.ConvertFrom

Tags: c#, parsing, generics

I have an existing generic method that is used to parse various numeric types from an XML file

```
public static Nullable<T> ToNullable<T>(this XElement element) where T : struct
{
    Nullable<T> result = new Nullable<T>();

    if (element != null)
    {
        if (element.HasElements) throw new ArgumentException(String.Format("Cannot convert complex element to Nullable<{0}>", typeof(T).Name));

        String s = element.Value;
        try
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s))
            {
                TypeConverter conv = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(T));
                result = (T)conv.ConvertFrom(s);
            }
        }
        catch { }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Unfortunately the input XML file is starting to include numeric strings that contain thousands separators (for example: 353,341.37).  The presence of the comma is now causing the above method to fail in the conversion, however, I'd like to parse this like any other numeric type

I know the various `Parse` and `TryParse` methods contain an overload that accepts a `NumberStyles` enum and will correct parse these values, but since I am using a generic method, those methods are not available until I want to create several type specific methods.

Is there a way to parse numeric types with thousands separators in a generic method?

Comment: Have you not found any of the provided answers helpful?

Comment: @OndrejJanacek it is more like this is for low priority side project, and since your answer really only pointed me in a direction, I haven't had time to investigate the various `CultureInfo` types to determine if your answer is actually a correct answer.  My first instinct though is if it was just a matter of the proper `CultureInfo` object, then the Parse & TryParse overloads that contain `NumberStyles` wouldn't be needed since they also contain a CultureInfo parameter too.

Comment: You have an [improperly formatted XML file](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#double).  Only one sane thing to ever do with it: reject it.  This is another programmer's problem.

Comment: What do you eventually use for T ?

Comment: When you say "...The presence of the comma is now causing the above method to fail..." do you mean the empty `catch` is executed?  If so, what exception is returned if you throw the exception to the calling method?

Comment: @KevinHogg sorry, I guess I should have elaborated one that.  It fails because it doesn't parse a valid double and returns a null.  there is no exception thrown to the calling method.

Answer (score 6):

You can also substitute the default DoubleConverter.

First, create a class that will be the converter:

```
    class DoubleConverterEx : DoubleConverter
    {
        public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value)
        {
            if (value is string)
            {
                string text = ((string)value).Trim();
                // Use the InvariantCulture, which accepts ',' for separator
                culture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

                NumberFormatInfo formatInfo = (NumberFormatInfo)culture.GetFormat(typeof(NumberFormatInfo));
                return Double.Parse(text, NumberStyles.Number, formatInfo);
            }
            return base.ConvertFrom(value);
        }
    }
```

Then register this class as the converter for double:

```
TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes(typeof(double), new TypeConverterAttribute(typeof(DoubleConverterEx)));
```

Now your converter will be called and since it both uses a culture with ',' separator AND passes NumberStyles value that allows your format, it will parse.

Test program:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes(typeof(double), new TypeConverterAttribute(typeof(DoubleConverterEx)));
        TypeConverter converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(double));
        string number = "334,475.79";
        double num = (double)converter.ConvertFrom(number);
        Console.WriteLine(num);
    }
```

Prints:

```
334475.79
```

You can do similar things for types that cause you problems (decimals, floats).

**Disclaimer**: The implementation of the converter itself is very basic, might need polish.
Hope that helps.

Comment: This won't work on my PC, because my CurrentCulture is cs_CZ - we use spaces as thousand separator.

Comment: Thank you, updated the answer to use `InvariantCulture` which **does** accept ',' as a separator. It should also solve your case (unless you need cs-CZ specifics when dealing with numbers).

Comment: You are correct, InvariantCulture **does** accept `','` as separator and the important thing is, that you use `NumberStyles.Number` in your `Double.Parse(text, NumberStyles.Number, formatInfo);`

Comment: Lots of code if you also want to support `NumberStyles` for `int`, `float`, etc... But you can easily check if the target type is any of those and do `result = (T)(double)conv.ConvertFrom(s)` when accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

You could use Reflection to get the correct `Parse` method and call that passing in any `NumberStyles` that you wish to use for your parsing:

```
Type type = typeof(T);
//you can change the below to get the different overloads of Parse
MethodInfo parseMethod = type.GetMethod("Parse", new[] { typeof(string), typeof(NumberStyles) });
if (parseMethod != null)
{
    result = (T)parseMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { s, NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint | NumberStyles.AllowThousands });
}
```

It's worth noting though that the `Parse` method does **not** take the `NumberFormat.NumberGroupSizes` into account when parsing. This means the above will still allow a format such as `00,0,0000,00` which you mention in your comment on @Merenwen's answer is not desired.

```
Console.WriteLine(decimal.Parse("00,0,0000,00", 
                  NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint | NumberStyles.AllowThousands));
//the above writes "0"
```

You could check the group lengths yourself and throw an exception if they are not what you are expecting. The following only takes into account the *first* separator character in the current culture (which works for me here in the UK!):

```
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s))
{
    string integerPart = s.Split(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator[0])[0];
    string[] groups = integerPart.Split(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator[0]);

    int maxGroupSize = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSizes.Max();

    for (int i = 0; i < groups.Length; i++)
    {
        //the first group can be any size that's less than or equal to the max groupsize
        //any other group has to be a size that's allowed in NumberGroupSizes
        if (!((i == 0 && groups[i].Length <= maxGroupSize)
            || CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSizes.Contains(groups[i].Length)))
        {
            throw new InvalidCastException(String.Format("Cannot convert {0} to Nullable<{1}>", s, typeof(T).Name));
        }
    }

    Type type = typeof(T);

    MethodInfo parseMethod = type.GetMethod("Parse", new[] { typeof(string), typeof(NumberStyles) });
    if (parseMethod != null)
    {
        result = (T)parseMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { s, NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint | NumberStyles.AllowThousands });
    }
}
```

That will throw an exception for `00,0,0000,00` or `3,53,341.37` but will return `353341.37` for `353,341.37`.

The only downside with the reflection method is the performance of invoking the call. To mitigate this you could create a delegate dynamically and call *that* instead. Creating a simple class that returns a `Func<string, Numberstyles, T>` and then calling the returned delegate roughly halves the execution time of the above code:

```
public static class ParseMethodFactory<T> where T : struct
{
    private static Func<string, NumberStyles, T> cachedDelegate = null;

    public static Func<string, NumberStyles, T> GetParseMethod()
    {
        if (cachedDelegate == null)
        {
            Type type = typeof(T);
            MethodInfo parseMethod = type.GetMethod("Parse", new[] { typeof(string), typeof(NumberStyles) });
            if (parseMethod != null)
            {
                cachedDelegate = (Func<string, NumberStyles, T>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<string, NumberStyles, T>), parseMethod);
            }
        }

        return cachedDelegate;
    }
}
```

Then your method becomes:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s))
{
    string integerPart = s.Split(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator[0])[0];
    string[] groups = integerPart.Split(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator[0]);

    int maxGroupSize = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSizes.Max();

    for (int i = 0; i < groups.Length; i++)
    {
        //the first group can be any size that's less than or equal to the max groupsize
        //any other group has to be a size that's allowed in NumberGroupSizes
        if (!((i == 0 && groups[i].Length <= maxGroupSize)
            || CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSizes.Contains(groups[i].Length)))
        {
            throw new InvalidCastException(String.Format("Cannot convert {0} to Nullable<{1}>", s, typeof(T).Name));
        }
    }
    //get the delegate from our factory
    Func<string, NumberStyles, T> parseDelegate = ParseMethodFactory<T>.GetParseMethod();

    if (parseDelegate != null)
    {
        //call the delegate
        result = parseDelegate(s, NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint | NumberStyles.AllowThousands);
    }
}
```

Comment: ...but same as in original answer from braintechd: *use `InvariantCulture`* (or "en-US"), not CurrentCulture. We (cs_CZ) write numbers like this: `12 345,6789 -> 12,345.6789`

Answer (score 1):

Just use the `ConvertFromString` method from the `TypeConverter` class which also accepts `CultureInfo` as a parameter.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kf8exy6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Converts the given text to an object, using the specified context and culture information.

```
public Object ConvertFromString(
    ITypeDescriptorContext context,
    CultureInfo culture,
    string text
)
```

Pass a proper `CultureInfo` (I don't actually know who uses the thousands separator) and you should be fine.

Comment: I have experimented with `InvariantCulture`, `CurrentCulture`, and a few sepecific cultures and nothing worked.

Comment: This has to work with en-US or similar CultureInfo (won't work with InvariantCulture for sure, CurrentCulture may work, but that will be system-settings-dependent).

Comment: I have to correct myself, it truly does not work, because e.g. `DoubleConverter` passes `NumberStyle.Float` instead of Number/Currency to `double.Parse`.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a generic class and factory method that handles the conversion and skip TypeDescriptor.   You will need to make a non-generic interface so we can return it.

```
public interface INumberConverter
{
    object ConvertFrom(string value);
    object ConvertFrom(CultureInfo culture, string value);
}
```

Then generic class that we can pass in the conversion method in the constructor.

```
public class GenericNumberConverter<T> : INumberConverter where T : struct
{
    private readonly Func<string, NumberStyles, NumberFormatInfo, T> _convertMethod;

    public GenericNumberConverter(Func<string, NumberStyles, NumberFormatInfo, T> convertMethod)
    {
        _convertMethod = convertMethod;
    }

    public object ConvertFrom(string value)
    {
        return ConvertFrom(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, value);
    }

    public object ConvertFrom(CultureInfo culture, string value)
    {
        var format = (NumberFormatInfo) culture.GetFormat(typeof (NumberFormatInfo));
        return _convertMethod(value.Trim(), NumberStyles.Number, format);
    }
}
```

Then to simplify things create a factory method for this generic class on the numeric types, I would put this in the same class as your ToNullable Extension method.

```
// return back non generic interface to use in method
private static INumberConverter ConverterFactory<T>() 
    where T : struct 
{
    var typeCode = Type.GetTypeCode(typeof(T));

    switch (typeCode)
    {
        case TypeCode.SByte:
            return new GenericNumberConverter<sbyte>(SByte.Parse);
        case TypeCode.Byte:
            return new GenericNumberConverter<byte>(Byte.Parse);
        case TypeCode.Single:
            return new GenericNumberConverter<float>(Single.Parse);
        case TypeCode.Decimal:
            return new GenericNumberConverter<decimal>(Decimal.Parse);
        case TypeCode.Double:
            return new GenericNumberConverter<double>(Double.Parse);
        case TypeCode.Int16:
            return new GenericNumberConverter<short>(Int16.Parse);
        case TypeCode.Int32:
            return new GenericNumberConverter<int>(Int32.Parse);
        case TypeCode.Int64:
            return new GenericNumberConverter<long>(Int64.Parse);
        case TypeCode.UInt16:
            return new GenericNumberConverter<ushort>(UInt16.Parse);
        case TypeCode.UInt32:
            return new GenericNumberConverter<uint>(UInt32.Parse);
        case TypeCode.UInt64:
            return new GenericNumberConverter<ulong>(UInt64.Parse);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Now your ToNullable becomes

```
public static T? ToNullable<T>(this XElement element) where T : struct
{
    var result = new T?();

    if (element != null)
    {
        if (element.HasElements) throw new ArgumentException(String.Format("Cannot convert complex element to Nullable<{0}>", typeof(T).Name));

        var s = element.Value;
        try
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s))
            {
                var numConverter = ConverterFactory<T>();
                if (numConverter != null)
                {
                    // interface returns back object so need to cast it
                    result = (T)numConverter.ConvertFrom(s);
                }
                else
                {
                    var conv = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(T));
                    result = (T)conv.ConvertFrom(s);
                }
            }
        }
        catch { }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### The code explains everything:

***(Reflection, Regex and small trick with static initialization)***

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace NumConvert {
    class Program {
        // basic reflection method - will accept "1,2,3.4" as well, because number.Parse accepts it
        static T ParseReflect<T>(string s) where T:struct {
            return (T)typeof(T).GetMethod("Parse", BindingFlags.Static|BindingFlags.Public, null, new Type[] {
                typeof(string), typeof(NumberStyles), typeof(IFormatProvider) }, null)
                .Invoke(null, new object[] { s, NumberStyles.Number, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture });
        }
        // regex check added (edit: forgot to escape dot at first)
        static string NumberFormat = @"^\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*(\.\d+)?$";
        static T ParseWithCheck<T>(string s) where T:struct {
            if(!Regex.IsMatch(s, NumberFormat))
                throw new FormatException("Not a number");
            return ParseReflect<T>(s);
        }
        // caching (constructed automatically when used for the first time)
        static Regex TestNumber = new Regex(NumberFormat);
        static class ParseHelper<T> where T:struct {
        //  signature of parse method
            delegate T ParseDelegate(string s, NumberStyles n, IFormatProvider p);
        //  static initialization by reflection (can use MethodInfo directly if targeting .NET 3.5-)
            static ParseDelegate ParseMethod = (ParseDelegate)Delegate.CreateDelegate(
                typeof(ParseDelegate), typeof(T).GetMethod("Parse",
                BindingFlags.Static|BindingFlags.Public, null, new Type[] {
                typeof(string), typeof(NumberStyles), typeof(IFormatProvider) }, null));
        //  this can be customized for each type (and we can add specific format provider as well if needed)
            static NumberStyles Styles = typeof(T) == typeof(decimal)
                ? NumberStyles.Currency : NumberStyles.Number;
        //  combined together
            public static T Parse(string s) {
                if(!TestNumber.IsMatch(s))
                    throw new FormatException("Not a number");
                return ParseMethod(s, Styles, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            }
        }
        // final version
        static T Parse<T>(string s) where T:struct {
            return ParseHelper<T>.Parse(s);
        }
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            Console.WriteLine(Parse<double>("34,475.79333"));
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
34475.79333
```

Different `Regex`, `NumberStyle` or even `CultureInfo` can be used for each type, just customize `ParseHelper<T>` with few type checks and ternary operators like I did with `ParseHelper<T>.Styles`.

***Edit: Forgot to escape `. -> \.` at first. `MethodInfo` can be used directly instead of `delegate` if you need to target .NET 3.5 or older. The meaning of regex:***

`^` - match string start
`\d` - match any digit
`{1,3}` - one to three (repeat specification)
`(,\d{3})*` - any number of `, digit digit digit`
`(\.\d+)?` - optional dot and non-zero number of digits
`$` - match string end

Check for `MethodInfo`/delegate existence can be added (if you ever use it with struct which is not number). Static variable can as well be initialized by static method/consturctor.

Answer (score -1):

Why not sanitize the string value if you expect it to be numeric?

```
String s = element.Value.Replace(",",String.Empty);
```

If you know you might have to deal with money types or other non numeric items you could try doing a more advanced Regex replacement.

Comment: While this would work, it would also introduce additional problems due to the fact that non-valid number formats such as `00,0,0000,00` would become valid numbers.  RegEx would probably work, but seems like there should be a better way